# Array subscript not an integer, despite being declared an int

Tags: c++, arrays

I keep getting the error that an array subscript needs to be an integer, which I understand. However, I'm pretty sure I declared what I'm using as the subscript to be an int. Can someone help me see where I'm messing up? This is a .cpp for a .h file.

```
Month::~Month() {
int size = getNumberOfDays();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    events[i] = events["", 0, 0, ""];
}
}

void Month::deleteExistingEvent() {
cout << "What is the day of the event you want deleted? (1-31) " << endl;
int deleteDay;
cin >> deleteDay;
deleteDay = deleteDay - 1;
events[deleteDay] = events["", 0, 0, ""];
}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. There is no way you need that much code for a compiler error like that one.

Comment: And *where* do you get the error? Can you try to remove irrelevant code? And please edit your question to include the *complete* error message, in full, unedited and with possible informational notes. Also some reformatting of the code could be nice, with some (consequent) indentation.

Comment: `events[i] = events["", 0, 0, ""];` doesn't make sense. What did you intend to do there?

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I got it with events[deleteDay] = events["", 0, 0, ""];   And I intended to empty the array, since I can't delete the object.

Comment: Also got it with events[i] = events["", 0, 0, ""];

Comment: Are you supposed to be constructing an `event` object? Because that's not what you're doing right now. Parentheses and square brackets do different things you know?

Comment: So `events` is an array of `Event` objects? Can the number of events in this array change (i.e. do you track the number of used positions?) or do you use some special value to represent an unused event?

Comment: Yeah, I just realized I should have been using () and Event. My stupid mess up.

Comment: Good. One comment on a tangent -- looking at that code, what will happen when the user enters some invalid day number? e.g. what if they enter a 0 or 32 or say 12345678 ?

Comment: What is the type for `event`?  Is it an array of character pointers?  An array of `std::string`?  A structure?

Answer (score 1):

In the expression

```
events["", 0, 0, ""]
```

the `operator[]` is called with 4 arguments. It can only take one argument. So, it's wrong, but the explanation of your error message depends on how the compiler parses this. Apparently it parses it as a single **comma expression** as argument. In that case the three first values are discarded, and the last one, an empty string literal `""`, is used as index.

Comment: OP error message indicates that `events` is an array, so no `operator[]` is involved.  Even if it were, `operator[]` takes 2 arguments. In this case (if `events` had class type), `events` would be the first argument and `"", 0, 0, ""` would be the second argument.

Comment: @M.M I'm sorry but all that you say here is just **wrong**. It's, uhm, argumentative.

Comment: Haha, puts "wrong" in bold and then accuses someone else of being argumentative

Comment: The "indicates" is exactly right, we don't really know, since the error message is not quoted. But *assuming* that it's an array, the "no `operator[]` is involved" is still just **wrong**. `operator[]` is its name, as used e.g. C++11 §13.6 "Built-in operators". That doesn't mean that you can use that name to invoke it. But its used in the standard to refer to it, so that name is good enough for me.

Comment: Note that candidate `operator[]` in that section takes 2 arguments

Comment: Re " Even if it were, operator[] takes 2 arguments", that's just **wrong** in this context. There is a context where it's true. But the existence of a different context where it would make sense does not make it more right than saying something possibly derogatory about negroes to President Obama, even though it could make sense in a different context. It's just incredibly dumb to argue that way. Shifting contexts.

Comment: There is an unlikely possibility that the context here is not clear to all readers, so: it's a call of `operator[]` on a class object or array, we don't know. It takes exactly one argument between `[` and `]`, and it cannot be overloaded with a version that takes more arguments. For this reason custom matrix classes commonly use `operator()` instead, which can be overloaded with an arbitrary number of arguments. These are the kinds of arguments referred to in the answer. We do not ordinarily refer to the class type object or array as an argument; doing so in the answer would just confuse.

Comment: @M.M. I can't see any common sense in what you write, I'm sorry. Repeating my answer with less clear words, and pretending that you say something different, is not meaningful. I stand by my first conclusion, that you're really just being argumentative, intentionally so.

Comment: Shrug. We can remove comments if you want.